# Automatically close the Archive Manager after extracting a file

Tags: archive

When I successfully extract an archive I'm greeted with a success dialog with the option to Quit, Show the Files or Close. Is there any setting that will automatically execute one of those options?

Comment: What's difference between Quit and Close?

Answer (score 4):

If you right click on the archive in the directory where you want to extract and click extract here, you won't have to click anything.

Comment: not much help since all downloads go to same local temp directory and once downloaded the extract must get targeted to good location ... a simple right click to extract will put expanded dir into your temp directory so its not reducing UI clicks etc ... Archive Manager itself used to have such an auto close its windows upon done checkbox which has recently been removed ... I'm on 16.10 and that checkmark is gone and Archive Manager does not have any Preference settings to alter this